# Cannot ungrab keyboard after XGrabKeyboard

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I'm developing an app that should freeze all input, both keyboard and mouse, for a period of time. I've tried using `XGrabKeyboard`, but I cannot revert its effect using `XUngrabKeyboard`, it does nothing.

Here's a minimal example you can easily compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display * dpy = nullptr;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);

    if(!dpy)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cerr << "Grabbing..." << std::endl;

    XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), false, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);

    std::cerr << "Waiting 2 secs, you shouldn't be able to type anything" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));


    std::cerr << "Ungrabbing..." << std::endl;
    XUngrabKeyboard(dpy, CurrentTime);

    std::cerr << "Try to type now" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
}
```

You can see that you cannot write anything anymore. I've tried clicking on the terminal, in case the focus is lost or anything, to no avail. Once the program finishes the keyboard is released.

Not sure if it has something to do with the parameters in the `XGrabKeyboard` call, I've tried modifying them (Sync vs Async, etc). But there's no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an `XSync(dpy, true);` (*) after `XUngrabKeyboard` makes the code behave in the way you expected. So possibly you have to process all the events you grabbed before the event queue resumes?

(*): don't actually do this, this is just to demonstrate that the problem is with the queued events

Also works:

```
XUngrabKeyboard(dpy, CurrentTime);
XEvent foo;
while (XPending(dpy)) XNextEvent(dpy, &foo);
```

Update - also works:

```
XFlush(dpy);
```

So... the problem is that the ungrab was not actually sent?

Comment: Thanks. It works properly when I test it in a command-line application, but the problem persists when I embed it in a Qt application. Whenever I call `QCoreApplication::exec` the ungrab is ignored. In fact, if I try to call grab again, I get `AlreadyGrabbed`.

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino that would probably deserve its own question with its own MCVE, not sure what exactly you are doing